# GUI for python linear regression model

Tags: python, user-interface, model

I created a linear regression model in python. It is a very simple model. Based on two previous year, I predict sales for the next year.

I want to create a GUI for business users who don't know how to use python.

The idea would be that they can go into the model and change variables, for example if they send out 4 e-mails per week instead of 5, their projected sales change.

Have you seen/created good examples of a simple GUI like that? Should I use something like PyQT or Kivy?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look into Tkinter, Kivy, or Bokeh... FWIW, there are many free, open-source GUI tools for linear regression (one being Gretl).

Comment: Thank you very much - have you seen a good example online of Tkinter, Kivy or Bokeh used with linear regression?

Comment: No, but least-squares regression is as simple as funneling input data through a second-grade level equation (like `y_hat = beta_naught + beta_1 * x_1 + beta_2 * x_2 + ... + beta_n * x_n`)... So your biggest problem is really getting the UI to be able to upload the input data (as a CSV or something).

Comment: GUIs in general are the hardest part about coding... it's largely about putting yourself in the place of a non-programmer and designing the interface to how they'll expect it to work. ie: drag and drop, copy paste, file menu with open and save... Tkinter is the de-facto standard python gui library, and there are plenty of examples out there for embedding matplotlib graphs on tkinter windows.

Comment: I would look into using Flask. Makes it easy to deploy the app the multiple users at once and also control changes to the source code (since it is just a website).

Comment: Go for Kivy . The plus point is that it is cross platform and the community is very active.You will find ample of examples  and when you finish your project with Kivy try putting it in Kivy-gardens.But yes do keep alternatives in mind.

Comment: Wow - Flask is awesome, thank you @scomes - trying it out right now

Comment: Thank You, @phunsukwangdu - I was looking exactly for advice like that; before I invest a lot of time into one option, I wanted to see which one others love the most

Comment: for Kivy-gardens, are you referring to the github? https://github.com/kivy-garden/

Comment: Yes! i was referring to same link.